# Why python returns None not True?

Tags: python, recursion

I expected my method call print(isFour(16)) returns "True", but it actually returned "None". What's wrong?

```
def isFour(int):
    if int == 4: return True
    if int > 0:
       isPositive(int/2)
        
print(isFour(16)) # expected output is True, but got None
```

Comment: `return isPositive(int/2)`

Comment: Because it *does not* `return` anything in the second `if` branch, and/or `isPositive` may not `return` anything…

Comment: Why is this tagged with [tag:recursion]?

Comment: Don't name a variable `int` (that's a builtin type).

Comment: Replace `isPositive(int/2)` with `isFour(int/2)` s.t. you actually have a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

It return None since int is not 4.

If you want it to return true if int is in the 4 times table you should write:

```
if int % 4 == 0: return True
```

Comment: Or just `return int % 4 === 0`, so it returns `True` or `False` always…

Comment: Please don't encourage naming a variable `int`!!